# Show custom Facebook app icon in news feed on Page photo upload

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When we create a regular text based Facebook status update (via Graph API), both the app name and icon will show in the news feed when viewed by a Page's fan.

However when we upload a photo to an album for that Page, the app icon will not show (uses the default Facebook photo album icon). The app name does show correctly.

Is this a limitation of how Facebook presents photo uploads in the news feed, or is there additional application configuration that must be done to allow it? I'm not interested in publishing custom Open Graph actions at the moment.

Our client has found an example of uploading photos to facebook through Instagram showing the custom application icon. Are they publishing an open graph action rather than a photo upload?

See the example below:

[image: Facebook App icon news feed example]

[image: Instagram upload showing icon]

Edit: Facebook bug to follow: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/447623711966656?browse=search_50bfaaaf247045772567103

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is intentional, and that all photos use the photos icon

{edit}
Instagram are using [Open Graph actions with attached photos](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/user-generated-photos/), not the regular photos API

Comment: Thanks Igy, it sure seems that way. Wondering if there's any way to override that action.

Comment: Check out the 2nd photo I attached, apparently instagram is showing their icon on uploads.

Comment: Added link above-  instagram are not using the photos api