# Direct creation of this object type is forbidden - 1611181

Tags: facebook, json, facebook-opengraph

So I'm trying to get it to post a sample photo using /me/photos.upload with the Open Graph API. I'm getting the following error

> {"error":{"type":"Exception","message":"Direct creation of this object type is forbidden.","code":1611181}}

I have looked all over, and have no clue what that means. Any ideas?

EDIT: Code:

```
include 'facebook.php';
include 'cURL.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'REMOVED',
  'secret' => 'REMOVED',
));

$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

$fields = array( 'access_token' => $access_token,
                    'photo' => 'http://treesroulette.com/app/test.html'
                    );

    $result = HTTP_POST("https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos.upload",// URL to query
                        $fields,                    // POST fields; associative array
                        USER_AGENT,                 // user-agent value
                        "",                         // cookie storage and retrieval
                        "",                         // proxy; type:ip:port[:user:pass]; supported types: http, socks5
                        true,                       // return the data or not
                        false,                      // include headers in the return data
                        "",                         // set value for REFERER header
                        true,                       // automatically follow "redirects" ("Location" header)
                        false); 
echo $result;
```

Comment: Can you post any of the code that's sending the request?

Comment: What is `/me/photos.upload` in that query? Did you see that in the documentation? you should be posting to `/me/photos`. Also, change your app secret immediately as you pasted your code without removing it!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong: there's no such endpoint as `/me/photos.upload` - the old REST API had a method called photos.upload but this isn't related to the current API's structure
Did you see that in the documentation? If so please add a comment below and i'll fix it.

You should be posting to `/me/photos`

See the `photos` connection of the [User object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) or this [guide to uploading photos](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/) in the blog

Also, change your app secret immediately as you pasted your code without removing it

Answer (score -1):

If you wants to upload photos and display your own icon I recommend you to read this thread: [Show custom Facebook app icon in news feed on Page photo upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13730737/show-custom-facebook-app-icon-in-news-feed-on-page-photo-upload)